# The computer wakes up every 5 minutes

Tags: systemd, suspend, laptop, hibernate

I try to set up my system (Arch Linux) to suspend when LID closed, and then to hibernate after 10 minutes. For this I try to use systemd's `suspend-and-hibernate`: I have

```
HandleLidSwitch=suspend-then-hibernate
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend-then-hibernate
```

in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`
and

```
HibernateDelaySec=600
```

in `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf`.

The problem is that the system wakes up every 5 minutes, so it never reaches the hibernation stage. In the logs I have something like this (you can see the full log here - https://pastebin.com/kDL3WSwD):

```
Jun 08 15:57:54 vindy systemd-logind[492]: Lid closed.
Jun 08 15:57:54 vindy systemd-logind[492]: Suspending, then hibernating...
...
Jun 08 15:57:55 vindy systemd[1]: Starting User suspend actions...
Jun 08 15:57:55 vindy wpa_supplicant[641]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Jun 08 15:57:55 vindy wpa_supplicant[641]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Jun 08 15:57:55 vindy wpa_supplicant[641]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlo1 disabled_11b_rates=0
Jun 08 15:57:56 vindy systemd[1]: Started User suspend actions.
Jun 08 15:57:56 vindy audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=suspend@okapi comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jun 08 15:57:56 vindy systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Jun 08 15:57:56 vindy systemd[1]: Starting Suspend; Hibernate if not used for a period of time...
Jun 08 15:57:56 vindy kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1654693076.621:79): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=suspend@okapi comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jun 08 15:57:56 vindy systemd-sleep[2200]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Jun 08 15:57:56 vindy kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Jun 08 15:57:56 vindy kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.009 seconds
Jun 08 16:02:56 vindy kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.039 seconds) done.
Jun 08 16:02:56 vindy kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Jun 08 16:02:56 vindy kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Jun 08 16:02:56 vindy kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Jun 08 16:02:56 vindy kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Jun 08 16:02:56 vindy kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
...
Jun 08 16:08:27 vindy kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.102 seconds) done.
Jun 08 16:08:27 vindy kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Jun 08 16:08:27 vindy kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Jun 08 16:08:27 vindy kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Jun 08 16:08:27 vindy kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Jun 08 16:08:27 vindy kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
...
Jun 08 16:13:58 vindy kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.097 seconds) done.
Jun 08 16:13:58 vindy kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Jun 08 16:13:58 vindy kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Jun 08 16:13:58 vindy kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Jun 08 16:13:58 vindy kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Jun 08 16:13:58 vindy kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
```

What causes this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

My laptop is a HP 845 G9 (Ryzen 6850HS).

I fixed this issue by replacing the Qualcomm FastConnect 6900 WiFi card with an Intel AX210.

I also disabled WWAN (Fibocom L860-GL Intel XMM 7560) in BIOS, since it breaks suspend.